# Changin layout background from preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I want to change the background of a layout through what the user selects from a ListPreference in the preferences. I am having a little bit of trouble doing this. I have set up the preferences in my Java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

}

and have an array set up for the ListPreference.

This is where I get the string from the preferences to change the background based on what is selected:

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    String strFavTeam = SP.getString("keyFavTeam", "0");

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.layout.main);

    if(strFavTeam.equals("0")){
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first_screen);
    }
    if(strFavTeam.equals("73")){
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tennessee_screen);
    }
    if(strFavTeam.equals("67")){
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.georgia_screen);
    }
```

I get a force close every time I choose Tennessee (which has a value of 73) from the ListPreference.

Please help!
Thanks!!

Comment: It would help if you also pasted in the exception thrown. I guess it's most likely to be a NullPointerException, but what throws it exactly? Check logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a view using a layout id. That's never going to return anything except `null`. You need to search for the id of the LinearLayout view you want to change. It will be something like `R.id.?` where `?` is whatever id you assigned to the view in main.xml.

Comment: I have changed that and now I am getting a different error.. an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.. not sure what this is but it says that it is at the ListPreference onDialogClosed. Do you want me to post the whole thing or is that enough?

Comment: There's no way of knowing what's wrong without more information. At least post the stack trace from logcat, along with the source for the method in which the exception is thrown.

Comment: It's difficult to read on here, can I email you so you can read the stack trace and code more easily?

Comment: Let's keep things on the forum. It sounds like you should start a new thread, since this is a different problem.

Comment: Ok sounds good. But from what you can see, you think I have the preferences set up correctly?

Comment: It would help if you posted your prefs xml, at a minimum.

Comment: This is my prefs.xml 

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Favorite Team">
  <ListPreference 
   android:title="Favorite Team" 
   android:summary="@string/prefs_pick_fav_team"
   android:key="keyFavTeam" 
   android:entries="@array/teams"
   android:entryValues="@array/teams_values" 
   android:defaultValue="0"
   /> 
 </PreferenceCategory>

Sorry, the formatting for comments is a little weird, I guess

Comment: I think the answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702486/android-preferences-error) addresses the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.