# Android Preferences error

Tags: android, preferences

In my app, I am trying to set up preferences that allows you to change the background image of a layout from a ton of choices in a ListPreference. 
My preferences xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Favorite Team">
    <ListPreference 
        android:title="Favorite Team" 
        android:summary="@string/prefs_pick_fav_team"
        android:key="keyFavTeam" 
        android:entries="@array/teams"
        android:entryValues="@array/teams_values" 
        android:defaultValue="0"
        />  
</PreferenceCategory>
```

The PreferencesActivity, which is also in the Manifest:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

And then this is the code from my onCreate of the screen I want the background changed:

```
SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    String strFavTeam = SP.getString("keyFavTeam", "0");

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_screen);

    if(strFavTeam.equals("0")){
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.first_screen);
    }
    if(strFavTeam.equals("73")){
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tennessee_screen);
    }
    if(strFavTeam.equals("67")){
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.georgia_screen);
    }
```

My problem is that I get a force close when I choose Tennessee (which has the value 73) from the ListPreference.

This is the stack trace from the LogCat:

```
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at android.preference.ListPreference.onDialogClosed(ListPreference.java:218)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at android.preference.DialogPreference.onDismiss(DialogPreference.java:383)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1047)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-14 23:43:35.535: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5581):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do to prevent this and move on with changing the background?

Thanks

Comment: What are the values for `@array/teams` and `@array/teams_values`?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the index you are using is greater than the size of the array. The actual line from the Android source that is failing is this:

```
String value = mEntryValues[mClickedDialogEntryIndex].toString();
```

So you probably have a mismatch in the length of the `@array/teams` and the `@array/teams_values` or you have a wholly incorrect value in there.

Comment: Well, there are 73 items for the teams and teams_values but a sample would be: 

<string-array name="teams">
     <item>Tennessee</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="teams_values">
     <item>73</items>

Are you saying that the length of each has to be the same?

Comment: Yep: they have to be the same size AND the indexes have to work.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, sorry. What do you mean by the indexes have to work?

Comment: @eric - I think Femi means that if the entries array is longer than the entryValues array, the user will be able to select an entry for which there is no corresponding value. This will result in the index being out of bounds. (It's also probably an error to have too many entryValues, but that won't cause a run-time exception.) The [docs for `ListPreference.setEntries`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setEntries(java.lang.CharSequence[])) explains this: _"Each entry must have a corresponding index in setEntryValues(CharSequence[])."_